# How to chunk operations on a list of very big numpy arrays and release memory

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, bigdata, chunking

I want to do operations (adding, multiplication, division) on very big numpy arrays included in a list as shown in Part I of the code.
list_arrays is a list of length 24 each element is 4D array of shape [360, 10, 241, 480] but I get memory error when I run the code.

I tried to chunk the list into smaller lists (Part II of code attached) and do the required operations on a chunk and save it to npy file then do the same to the next chunk until I am done with all of them (Part III).

But after looping over a chunk the memory still busy. How to release memory after looping over a chunk to get space for the next chunk.

```
##### Part I ######
n_l = []
for i in range(len(list_arrays)):
    if i ==0:
        m = list_arrays[i]/2 * 8
    else:
        m = ((list_arrays[i]+list_arrays[i-1])/2) * 8
    n_l.append(m)
#n_l is a new list of same length as list_arrays but includes arrays with new values
##########################################

##### Part II ######
def chunking(l, n): ##Chunking function
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i+n]
chunks = list(chunking(list_arrays, 5)) 
# chunks is a list of 5 lists each list includes five 4D arrays
##########################################

##### Part III ######
for i in range(len(chunks)):
    if i == 0:
        for ii in range(len(chunks[i])):
            if ii == 0:
                m = (chunks[i][ii] /2) * 8
            else:
                m = ((chunks[i][ii] + chunks[i][ii -1]) /2) * 8
        np.save('./chunk_%d/%d.npy'%i, m)
    if i != 0:
        for ii in range(len(chunks[i])):
            if ii == 0:
                m = ((chunks[i][ii]+ chunks[i-1][-1]) /2) * 8
            else:
                m = ((chunks[i][ii] + chunks[i][ii -1]) /2) * 8
        np.save('./chunk_%d/%d.npy' %i, m)
#########################################
```

I expect 25 npy files each file includes an array of same size but with new values

Comment: not sure if I understand your code but at this line: `for ii in range(chunks[i]):` perhaps you meant: `for ii in range(len(chunks[i])):`

Comment: Please add some more informations about the real . Is it allowed to overwrite the input data? Are there any other dependencies apart from numpy in the real problem? How often do you access different list entries?

Comment: Yes Vince you are right I have edited that. 

For max, the full code is longer and 1st stage of computations which is separated gives the list of arrays list of arrays as output and then I use it for the following computations mentioned above. And I do not want to overwrite input data. I am not sure if this answer clarify that for you.